# Should homework questions that are otherwise not problematic be left open?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This is a pretty uncommon scenario here, but it appears that [someone has posted what looks a lot like a homework question to the site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/66007/73). The twist here is that the question itself is very relevant to the site, and if the OP would have put any effort into modifying the question to appear as if it was their own, we would never have noticed. Is there any issue with leaving this question open?

Answer (score 5):

As the question has been copied from some [APS material](https://www.aps.org/programs/education/ethics/upload/Ethics-Case-Studies-Student-Edition.pdf) and they [provide an answer](http://www.aps.org/programs/education/ethics/undergraduate/plagarism-discussion.cfm). I do not see a place for this particular question. It seems weird to just repost material from other sites.

Comment: It might be a good question if the OP had some good reason why the existing answer was not sufficient (besides for "My ethics professor said we can't just plagiarize the APS answer") or did not apply. But as far as I can tell, the OP just didn't even bother to Google it and find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I say **leave it open**.

1. There's really no way to police this.
2. The question is interesting; removing it punishes ourselves.
3. This happens so rarely that doesn't really need a policy.

---

EDIT: I posted this before @ff524 found the exact question, along with answers, already online. Given that update, I'm a bit more hesitant... as @Strongbad says, we don't need to repost stuff from other sites just for the heck of it.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear where it came from and that it is a case study.

Comment: In the abstract, it might be OK. This question, not so much.